# Solving $\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-verification

> Solve $\sin\left(\frac\theta2\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

I have a slight concern about this question. Suppose that I use the half-angle identity to solve the problem over only $[0,2\pi)$:

$$\pm\sqrt{1-\cos\theta\over2}=-{1\over2}$$ $${1-\cos\theta\over2} = {1\over4}$$ $$\cos\theta = {1\over2}$$ $$\theta = {\pi\over3},{5\pi\over3}.$$

Now if I want to extend this to find *all* the solutions over the reals, why can I not simply just add $2\pi n$ to it and be done? Isn't the period of $\cos\theta$ determined to be $2\pi$? I know that the period of $\sin\left({\theta\over2}\right)$ is $T={2\pi\over1/2} = 4\pi$, so why do I have a difference here?

I guess my question is, why do I end up with two different periods I could use? According to WolframAlpha, the answer requires the $4\pi$ period, but I'm not sure *why*. Is it because squaring the problem transforms the problem to something else that causes extraneous solutions to arise?

---

For the record, I originally solved the problem by saying $u = {\theta\over2}$, which means $$\sin(u)=-{1\over2} \implies u = {7\pi\over6} + 2\pi n \text{ or } u = {11\pi\over6}+2\pi n$$ $$\implies {\theta\over2} = {7\pi\over6} + 2\pi n \text{ or } {\theta\over2} = {11\pi\over6}+2\pi n$$ $$\implies \theta = {7\pi\over3} + 4\pi n \text{ or } \theta = {11\pi\over3} + 4\pi n,$$

which is the solution that WolframAlpha provides. However, I wanted to see how to solve the problem using the half-angle identity.

Comment: if $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ then $\frac {\theta}{2} \in [0,\pi)$ and $\sin \frac {\theta}{2} \ge 0$ there are no solutions with this domain restriction.  If you use the half angle identity, you will need to be careful where you evaluate $\theta$ such that $\sin \frac {\theta}{2}$ maps to the correct quadrant.

Comment: When you are squaring both sides, you do realize that you may add extraneous solutions?

Comment: $2\pi$ is the period of $\sin \theta$ but why would it be the period of $\sin \frac {\theta}{2}$.  After all, what is the period of $\sin(\frac {\theta}{5000})$?  Is it $2\pi$.  Does $\sin( \frac {\theta}{5000} )= \sin(\frac{\theta + 2\pi}{5000})$?  How could it be when $\sin(\frac{\theta + 2\pi}{5000}) = \sin (\frac {\theta}{500} + \frac {\pi}{2500})$.  The period of $\sin$ is $2\pi$; not $\frac {\pi}{2500}$.  Can you answer your own question now?

Comment: $\sin (\frac {\theta} 2)=-\frac 12 \implies \cos \theta = \frac 12$.  But $ \cos \theta = \frac 12 \not \implies \sin (\frac {\theta} 2)=-\frac 12$

Answer (score 1):

> Now if I want to extend this to find *all* the solutions over the reals, why can I not simply just add $2\pi n$ to it and be done? Isn't the period of $\cos\theta$ determined to be $2\pi$? I know that the period of $\sin\left({\theta\over2}\right)$ is $T={2\pi\over1/2} = 4\pi$, so why do I have a difference here?

It seems that you think 
$$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=-\frac 12\tag1$$
is equivalent to 
$$\cos\theta=\frac 12\tag2$$
But $(2)$ is **not** equivalent to $(1)$. Take, for example, $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$.

$(2)$ is just a necessary condition, so you cannot simply add $2\pi n$.